# Birmingam - Frankfurt - Toronto connections

Tags: transit, luggage, short-connections, fra

We are flying from Birmingham to Frankfurt to Toronto. Our single e-ticket displays all of our flights. There will be 1 hour 15 minutes once we land in Frankfurt to catch Toronto flight which is at the same terminal (1).

Will our bagagge be transfered for us or will we need to pick it up and check it again ourselves? The flight to Toronto is with Lufthansa as well.

I feel very stressed about only having 1hr15 mins in an airport I have never been before. Any insightis much appreciated.

Comment: Since both your flights are with Lufthansa, yes they will do the transfer of luggage for you. You will receive two boarding passes from your point of departure. As for the transit time, you can refer to this question. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72314/layover-in-frankfurt-for-1h40m-is-it-enough-what-happens-otherwise

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Plane from Birminham arrived early so we had plenty of time in Frankfurt. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yikes, this is tight. Apparently LH thinks they can do it otherwise they wouldn't have sold you the ticket and if you miss the flight Toronto they will rebook you on the next for free and may even put you up in a hotel overnight, if needed.

Terminal 1 has 4 "piers" what are essentially individual terminals by themselves. A, B, C & Z. Some of these are really far apart and not all allow airside connection.

UK is not Shengen so you may be lucky and get all your Canadian entry checks in Birmingham and can do an airside transfer in FRA. I would call LH and ask for gate info and ask whether this will be an airside transfer. If you have to go through security and passport, this seems extremely tight.

Answer (score 1):

1 hour 15 minutes should be more than enough to transfer between two non-schengen flights at Frankfurt Airport.

If you are travelling on one ticket, your luggage will be checked through and arriving from Birmingham (usually terminal 1A) and departing to Torono (usually terminal 1B), you can stay air-side and will not have to pass immigration or additional security checks.

Even check-in and bag-drop for new passengers do not close until 40 minutes before departure for the Lufthansa flight to Toronto.

Comment: Be very careful to read and follow the signs, especially where connecting flight passengers are separated from those going to baggage claim and exit.